# Proving that formulas are BHK-valid

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I have been studying Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov (BHK) interpretation lately, and I want to prove that the formulas below are BHK-valid.

1. $(A \vee B) \supset (B \vee A)$
2. $A \supset (B \supset A)$
3. $(A \supset (B \supset C)) \supset ((A \wedge B) \supset C)$
4. $((A \wedge B) \vee (A \wedge C)) \supset (A \wedge (B \vee C))$

I tried to the following for (1), though I don't know whether it is correct.

$\delta$ is a pair $(v, \eta)$ where $v$ is either left and $\eta \rhd \{A\}$ or right and $\eta \rhd \{B\}$.

$\gamma$ waits for input $\delta$ and returns as output the procedure $\pi$. Input for $\pi$ is $\eta$, where  $\eta \rhd \{A\}$ or $\eta \rhd \{B\}$. And output of $\pi$ is a proof of $B$ or $A$.

Comment: May we assume that these are the rules for the [BHK-interpretation](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionistic-logic-development/#1.1) ?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the stuff that I study, but written a bit differently. Here is my version. http://prntscr.com/95pile

Comment: Regarding the EDIT, it looks quite good. The procedure $\pi$ takes as input $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ and have to unpack $\delta$ to recover $\eta$; thus, with $\eta$ the procedure apply $\eta$ to $\gamma_1$ in order to recover $\gamma_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

For (1), I think that, having a *proof* $\gamma$ of $A \lor B$, i.e.

> $\gamma = \langle \nu, \gamma_0 \rangle$, where either $\nu = \text {left}$ and $\gamma_0$ proves $A$ or $\nu = \text {right}$ and $\gamma_0$ proves $B$,

we have a *procedure* transforming $\gamma$ into

> $\gamma' = \langle \nu', \gamma_0 \rangle$, where either $\nu' = \text {left}$ and $\gamma_0$ proves $B$ or $\nu' = \text {right}$ and $\gamma_0$ proves $A$.

Thus, informally, the "procedure" exchanges "left" and "right" from $\nu$ to $\nu'$.

For (2), having a proof $\gamma_0$ of $A$, we can define a procedure $\gamma$ transforming this proof into a proof of $B \supset A$, i.e. into a procedure that, given a proof $\gamma_1$ of $B$, produce the previous proof $\gamma_0$ of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer. Can you please check out this problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547669/how-to-show-validity-of-a-skolem-formula-in-lk